# Can gravity be utilized to generate hydropower in a clean, repeatable fashion without rivers or lakes?

Tags: energy, newtonian-gravity, electricity, power, perpetual-motion

[image]I came up with this idea today and am just wondering if it is feasible. It is much easier to communicate via images so I drew the attached image to convey it. The key concept is rolling a ball in order to get water back up to the top so that it can fall back down through a turbine again and again just using gravity. What I like about this idea is that it's very simple. Not a whole lot of moving parts here - just a pendulum and a rolling ball with water in it. All that is required is a computer to catch and release the pendulum once all the water has fallen through the turbine. Basically I'm trying to use gravity in a clever way to "reset" the system so the water can fall repeatedly. The pendulum is always caught and reset on each side after a single swing so I'm not concerned with friction or air loss. The pendulum is not generating the energy, the falling water within the ball is. The pendulum is just used to roll the ball so that the water gets 100% back up to the top using nothing but gravity to do it.

NOTE: The pendulum does not swing back and forth. It is CAUGHT and RESET after a single swing. This is not perpetual motion.

Comment: Have you thought through the process the pendulum uses to reset the system, and the energy balances associated with it?  As a general rule, if you think you have found a way to generate free perpetual energy, you haven't.  People have spent a *lot* of time triyng to come up with clever ways to do this, and so far 100% of them have had flaws.  Usually it comes in terms of an operation that we thought was free, but actually had an energy cost.  Since you think the pendulum is doing something special, its a good place to focus.

Comment: The pendulum is caught after each swing to the other side. It does not swing back and forth. I can see why you may think that but it is just there to initiate the ball rolling. It gets "reset" when caught by the hook.

Comment: Once the pendulum "initiates" the ball rolling, what causes it to continue rolling?  An off-center weighted ball doesn't roll without considerable energy input

Comment: As the pendulum reaches the other side the TILT of the container will cause the ball to roll to the other side of the container it is in.

Comment: I'd encourage testing that with a coffee can with a rock or a roll of quarters taped to one side.  See if you can make a tilt cause the coffee can to roll.  Then figure out how much energy you had to put into the system to make it happen.

Comment: Energy is not put into the system. The TILT utilizes gravity, which cause the ball to roll. Are you familiar with pendulums? In looking at my diagram do you not think that the pendulum will make it to the other side just as drawn?

Comment: I would expect the ball to slide rather than roll.  If you had enough friction to prevent this sliding, it will either not roll or it will roll exactly once and then fail to have enough energy to roll again.  This is why I recommend playing with a an off-balance coffee can or similiar.  You'll find it behaves differently than you expect.

Comment: Yeah I want it to roll exactly once, thus bringing the water back up to the top of the ball. I'm not sure why you think it would slide rather than just roll. Imagine you put a basketball on a teeter-totter then sit on the other end. Does the ball slide or roll?

Comment: Rolling an off center ball requires putting energy in it.  It raises the height of the mass (the water), which requires putting energy into it.  Particularly, it needs to have $mgh$ put into it, where m is the mass of water, g is 9.8m/s^2 and h is the change in the height of the center of mass of the water.  If you don't enough energy in, it just rolls back.  If you're thinking of a basketball on a teeter totter, then you are thinking of a balanced ball rather than an off-center weighted ball.

Comment: Imagine you set this off-center weighted ball onto a blanket two people are holding level. Then one person starts to lower their side of the blanket. Are you suggesting the ball will just slide down towards the lower person or will it roll towards the lower person?

Comment: It will not roll unless you tip the blanket enough (which is a function of the ratio of the radius of the ball and the position of the weight).  This is a major part of why the [Bozo the Clown punching bags](https://www.amazon.com/Original-Bozo-3-D-Bop-Bag/dp/B00067TAWG/ref=asc_df_B00067TAWG/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=312201637912&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=6454184188973046721&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9030241&hvtargid=pla-556341338559&psc=1) work.  Balls don't roll just because they're on an incline.  They roll if doing so decreases potential energy.

Comment: You said “Energy is not put into the system”. Then it violates the conservation of energy and cannot work. “do you not think that the pendulum will make it to the other side”. It definitely will not.

Comment: Dale - it takes energy to lift the pendulum to it's starting height. After that it is constantly caught and reset by the computerized hooks. Of course it will make it to the other side - do you think it will magically stop mid swing? I know the ball won't just sit there stationary however I cannot say for certain it won't just slide to the other side as suggested and I cannot say that the tilt/incline achieved will be enough to cause the ball to roll rather than slide.

Comment: You said “Of course it will make it to the other side”. No, it will not. Assuming no friction or other dissipation it will only make it to the point where the center of mass is at the same height as when it was released. Because of the redistribution of the water this will not be close enough for the hook to catch it.

Comment: The sphere containing the water cannot magically rotate back to an upward position. As the pendulum swings gravity will keep the sphere oriented such that the water remains at the bottom. Gravity will not generate enough $KE_{rot}$ to bring it back to the top. If the pendulum initiates the roll, where will the additional rotational energy required for the sphere to rotate 180 degrees come from?

Comment: There are too many things wrong with this setup to mentioned. It will not work. but good thought experiment try.

Answer (score 1):

The center of gravity of the system will rise only as high on the right as it was on the left. Supposing that the rolling happens as designed, and the mass of everything other than the water is negligible, the center of gravity of the water will be the same on the right as on the left. The pendulum therefore won't reach the hook unless you lift it the rest of the way, which will have the same energy cost as pumping the water into the upper tank on the left would have.